# Enabling php_oci8_11g extension in php.ini via Chef recipe for Linux

Tags: php, linux, oracle, apache, chef-solo

We have a website which is written with PHP and Oracle as backend database. We are trying to automate the deployment process via Chef-Solo. This runs on AWS EC2 instance.

Our cookbooks include

1. apache2
2. ourwebsite
3. aws
4. yum

I have enabled PHP module in apache2, and I can see php pages running on the instance. We need to install oracle extension for PHP. In windows, enabling php_oci8_11g extension in the php.ini file is required. I am not sure what is the procedure for linux.

Also, there is no PHP5-oracle cookbook available. Do we need to write our own cookbook for that? I so can someone please share any resources available on enabling php extensions via Chef?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the steps given [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html) in oracle website for installing oracle instant client for linux (See section: Enabling the PHP OCI8 Extension on Linux)

I have installed the following cookbooks:

- aws
- yum
- build-essential
- apache2
- oracle-instantclient
- oracle-instantclient::sdk
- php
- ourwebsite

Inside ourwebsite default recipe I added the following code

```
include_recipe 'php'

service 'httpd' do
  action :stop
end

php_pear "oci8" do
  action :install
end

service 'httpd' do
  action :start
end
```

Explanation: oracle-instantclient and oracle-instantclient::sdk will download the rpms from the url you have given, and installs the client. You need build-essentials for C compiler which is needed while installing oci8. php_pear resource will install oci8.